# FFmpeg Overlay during Encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I want to overlay a number(12345) using FFmpeg during encoding of frames from mobotix cameras.
Encoding form is through H.264 format using FFmpeg

Could anyone help me out in overlaying?

Comment: Use [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter.

Comment: Drawtext examples are all in linux environment. Any code available in C for windows?

Comment: Are you using ffmpeg C API or CLI?

Comment: C API, where I am converting raw frames from camera to h.264 format. Now I want to Overlay a text during this encoding time. But the Drawtext.c file has Ubuntu includes. And I want in Windows Environment.

Comment: I compile ffmpeg with that filter on Win7 regularly with no issues or changes although with gcc. Are you referring to `<sys/types.h>` and `<sys/stat.h>`?

Comment: no I am not referring to  <sys/types.h> and <sys/stat.h>

Comment: You could specify which includes you are referring to.